# Is there any way to call Inform7 from the command line?

Tags: inform7

is there any way to play inform7 from the command line? I'd like to write some automated test script that plays the play with certain commands and don't want to do it manually. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: IIRC there is a replay feature inside Inform games (assuming it survived to I7). I doubt there is a way to play through just from the command line.

Comment: Yeah there still is a replay button which really helps for manual testing. Still haven't figured out a way to write some automated test scripts that can be called from outside of Inform though.

Answer (score 4):

This is easiest to do with the CLI Linux package of Inform 7. It contains a perl CLI script you can run, but you may also like to consider this alternative script I wrote: https://github.com/i7/kerkerkruip/blob/master/tools/build-i7-project

You can invoke this with

```
build-i7-project -p "Project Folder"
```

(Leave off the `.inform`.)

You can also run the binaries which are installed with the IDE packages by themselves instead of installing the CLI Linux package. The command line options are probably mostly the same in other operating systems, but you may need to change them slightly. If you can't get it to work, compare with what the Inform 7 IDE says when you build with it.

Comment: You could use Docker to run the CLI Linux Inform 7 in macOS or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want to do is periodically run some test scripts that verify that your work is still performing as expected, then Inform 7 has the capability do do that from within the IDE. Take a look at [chapter 24.2](http://inform7.com/book/WI_24_2.html) of *Writing with Inform* for details. In combination with good use of the Skein, this should handle the more common unit-testing requirements.

Of course, if you're doing something more outré, running bash scripts from the command line may wind up being the way to go. Still, don't do any more work than you have to. :)